# JavaScript: Trouble with Arrays in localStorage (using JSON Parse)

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

New to JS. I am trying to store an array in localStorage by converting it to a string using JSON, and then parsing back into an array when I retrieve it from another page on my site. However, I'm not seeing what I expect in the console log after parsing back into an array.

I have not worked with JSON before, so maybe I am doing something wrong. I couldn't find that there was anything I needed to import on my script page to use JSON, but please let me know if I'm missing something.

**Example code:**

Page 1 HTML:

```
<div class="test">Some text.</div>
<div class="test">Some text.</div>
<div class="test">Some text.</div>
```

Page 1 JS:

```
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
console.log(allDivs);
  // Console Log Output: NodeList(3) [div.test, div.test, div.test]
localStorage.setItem("content", JSON.stringify(allDivs));
```

Page 2 JS:

```
var originalArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("content"));
console.log(originalArray);
  // Console Log Output: {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
```

I was hoping that after retrieving on Page 2, the console log would bring back what I saw when I console-logged my original array on Page 1 (`NodeList(3) [div.test, div.test, div.test]`). Instead, I see that it is converting into some key-value pairs instead of the original array.

How can I return the original array on Page 2? I would like to be able to set up a function that loops through that array on Page 2, without having to manually copy all of the content on Page 1 to a hidden container on Page 2, as the Page 1 content changes daily.

If there is a better way overall that I should approach this, please let me know! I tried a few other things like `fetch(url)` and jQuery `$.load` as well, but was having trouble understanding how to make those options work with my code.

Comment: NodeList is not an Array

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(Array.from(allDivs))`

Comment: Ok after trying Array.from(allDivs) I'm closer, it does return an array, but the contents of the array are the key-value pairs again, like this: [Array(3)]0: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]. Perhaps I should rephrase - is there a way to bring back the original Node List?

Comment: Don't store HTML in localStorage. Store the data necessary to render the HTML, in localStorage, then rerender the HTML after pulling the data out. Trying to keep a whole DOM (with all its relationships) intact is a complex endeavor not worth the few milliseconds it takes to rerender the HTML.

Comment: Could you tell more about what you're trying to accomplish in a broader sense; the goal your solution is trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodelist is a collection of nodes which are objects with many properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList
what you could do is:

```
const result = [];
for (const div of allDivs) {
    result.push(div.innerHTML);
    localStorage.setItem("content", JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

or alternatively:

```
const result = Array.from(allDivs).map((div) => div.innerHTML);
localStorage.setItem("content", JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Ah, this looks like what I will need! Thanks, let me try implementing this on my original code and see if I can get it working.